# is there any way to turn off mapreduce in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm studying hadoop 2.7.2 in centos 6.5. Also, I'm interesting in hadoop mapreduce.

Question 1. While studing about that, i just think "is there any way to turn off mapreduce in hadoop?". I found serveral options in mapred-site.xml. As i see, there are no options about turn off mapreduce.

Question 2. When using Hadoop, in any way mapreduce must work?

help me please~

Comment: MapReduce is an application you can run on top of Hadoop. You can't turn it off, you just can choose not to use it.

Comment: could you let me know how not to use mapreduce?